# RecursionError when inheriting from float and using str and repr

Tags: python, string, inheritance, repr, recursionerror

I was testing some features in Python for fun ;)
But I have a recursion error that I don't understand

```py
class Test(float):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        return super().__new__(cls, value)

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<value: {str(self)}>'


test = Test(12)
print(test)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\test_float.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(test)
  File "C:\temp\test_float.py", line 6, in __str__
    return super().__str__()
  File "C:\temp\test_float.py", line 9, in __repr__
    return f'<value: {str(self)}>'
  File "C:\temp\test_float.py", line 6, in __str__
    return super().__str__()
  File "C:\temp\test_float.py", line 9, in __repr__
    return f'<value: {str(self)}>'
...the above 2 errors repeated many times...
  File "C:\temp\test_float.py", line 6, in __str__
    return super().__str__()
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

The line `return super().__str__()` should call `float.__str__()` and just returns '12'.

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Please post the full error traceback!

Comment: Your repr calls str, which calls float's str, which defers to repr, which is an infinite recursion. You could call `super().__repr__` in your repr method, instead of calling `str(self)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core issue is that `float.__str__(self)` will call `self.__repr__()` rather than `float.__repr__(self)`.

Not only does that mean that you have an infinite recursion from `Test.__repr__` to `Test.__str__` to `float.__str__` back to `Test.__repr__`, it means that `Test.__str__` is going to print the same thing as `Test.__repr__`, which I assume you don't want since you went to the effort of reimplementing it.

Instead I think you want:

```
class Test(float):
    def __str__(self):
        return super().__repr__()
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<value: {super().__repr__()}>'
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `__repr__` calls your `__str__`, which calls the super's `__str__`, which defers to `repr`, which calls your `__repr__`, which is an infinite recursion. You could call `super().__repr__` in your `__repr__` method, instead of calling `str(self)`.

```
class Test(float):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        return super().__new__(cls, value)

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<value: {super().__repr__()}>'
```

```
>>> Test(12)
<value: 12.0>
```